# Lambda expressions : n3290 draft

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

A point from n3290 ISO draft:
Lambda expressions : section 5.1.2, para 6:

```
         "The closure type for a lambda-expression with no 
      lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const
      conversion function to pointer to function having the same
      parameter and return types as the closure type’s function
      call operator. The value returned by this conversion
      function shall be the address of a function that, when
      invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure
      type’s function call operator."
```

Can any one explain this point with an example please ?

Comment: Is there a particular part of this that you find confusing?  Is there some term that you don't understand?  Do you not understand what the required behavior is?

Comment: @ James :typedef int(*pf)(int);
int callback(pf func){returnfunc(3);}                                pf func = [](int k) ->int{ k--; return k;};

Comment: @ James : is that above ..example ..represents that above statement ... iam a bit confused regarding the point ." same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator " ..but iam anable to prove in terms of program ..way

Comment: In a nutshell, "non-capturing lambdas *are* just ordinary free functions" (they just don't have a name) -- at least when you need them to be. (For instance you could pass one to the old C `sort`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short answer**

This just means that lambdas not capturing anything can be converted into a function pointer with the same signature:

```
auto func = [](int x) { return x * 2; };
int (*func_ptr)(int) = func; // legal.

int y = func_ptr(2); // y is 4.
```

And a capture makes it illegal:

```
int n = 2;
auto func = [=](int x) { return x * n; };
int (*func_ptr)(int) = func; // illegal, func captures n
```

**The long answer**

Lambdas are shorthand to create a functor:

```
auto func = [](int x) { return x * 2; };
```

Is equivalent to:

```
struct func_type
{
    int operator()(int x) const { return x * 2; }
}

func_type func = func_type();
```

In this case `func_type` is the "closure type" `and operator()` is the "function call operator".  When you take the address of a lambda, it is as if you declared the `operator()` static and take its address, like any other function:

```
struct func_type
{
    static int f(int x) { return x * 2; }
}

int (*func_ptr)(int) = &func_type::f;
```

When you have captured variables, they become members of `func_type`.  `operator()` depends on these members, so it can't be made static:

```
struct func_type
{
    int const m_n;

    func_type(int n) : m_n(n) {}
    int operator()(int x) const { return x * m_n; }
}

int n = 2;
auto func = func_type(n);
```

An ordinary function has no notion of member variables.  Keeping with this thought, lambdas can only be treated as an ordinary function if they also have no member variables.

Comment: do you know whether the compiler is supposed to diagnose the no capture or not ? For example if I write `[=](int x){return x*2;}` then I do not capture anything even though I specified to capture by value.

Comment: [=] merely changes the default capture -- you can still convert to function pointer so long as you don't actually capture anything.

Comment: @ Cory what about this ... statement " The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when   invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator" ,can u please explain...this also

Answer (score 2):

This is (roughly) saying that the new C++0x lambda has a conversion operator to a function pointer (with the same signature).  When you call that function pointer, it is just like invoking the lambda (with the same parameters passed).

> ...a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture...

"with no lambda-capture" means that you didn't capture any variables from the containing scope, so it is self-contained.

From this blurb, I'm thinking that you can't do the conversion if you captured variables (e.g. from the local scope):

```
// this is fine...
std::vector<int> some_list;
int total = 0;
std::for_each(some_list.begin(), some_list.end(), [&total](int x) {
  total += x;
});

// so is this...
int total = 0;
auto someLambda = [](int x) { return x * 5; };
int (*pointerToLambda)(int) = someLambda;
someFunction(pointerToLambda);

// this won't work, because of capture...
int total = 0;
auto someLambda = [&total](int x) { total += x; return total; };
int (*pointerToLambda)(int) = someLambda;
someFunction(pointerToLambda);
```

Comment: They don't guarantee it if you capture anything, because they can't. The captured values are stored in the object, so it's `operator()` can't be static, so it can't be converted to static/non-member function pointer.