# What is this compiler error when using a lambda as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, c++11, lambda

## Edit:

This has been reported as a VS2012 C++ compiler bug on Microsoft Connect [(link)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788426/vs2012-c-compiler-lambda-type-as-template-parameter#details).

Nov. 11, 2014: Microsoft has responded saying the fix for this bug should show up in the next major release of Visual C++.

---

I've been struggling with a VS2012 compiler error message I don't understand, so I trimmed down the problem to what seems like the bare minimum.

I'm building the following `main.cpp` using VS2012:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    T x;
    A(A&& other) : x(std::move(other.x)) { }
    A(T&& x) : x(std::move(x)) { }
};

template <typename T>
A<T> build(T&& x)
{
    return A<T>(std::move(x));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto f = []()
    {
        return build([](){}); //error here
    };
    return 0;
}
```

The salient point is that I'm trying to use a lambda as the template type `T` of the `build` function.  The error message I get is:

```
1>  main.cpp
1>C:\test\main.cpp(21): error C2664: 'A<T>::A(A<T> &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'A<T>' to 'A<T> &&'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=void (__cdecl *)(void)
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=main::<lambda_c3c618d445b3cb24eede9bf304860ad7>::()::<lambda_4240e93016e3e420ff8383c9350ae130>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=void (__cdecl *)(void)
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'A<T>' to 'A<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=main::<lambda_c3c618d445b3cb24eede9bf304860ad7>::()::<lambda_4240e93016e3e420ff8383c9350ae130>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=void (__cdecl *)(void)
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

I've done my research and looked up the page for the error message ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd(v=vs.71).aspx)), but I still can't figure out what the problem is. Could you please explain this compiler error?

---

## edit

Something is definitely weird here. If I change the code in `main` to look like this:

```
auto f = []()
{
    int* n = new int(0);
    auto g = [=](){ return *n; };
    *n++;
    return build<decltype(g)>(std::move(g));
};
```

I get an error message suggesting that `T=int (__cdecl *)(void)` in the call to build - which would mean that `decltype(g)` is giving me a function pointer? Huh? I'm capturing a pointer by value and then modifying it afterwards - shouldn't it *have* to create a functor - and one that has no cast to function pointer? Maybe I'm not understanding something.

See related: [Lambda expressions : n3290 draft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674506/lambda-expressions-n3290-draft)

---

Also, if this *is* a bug in the VS2012 compiler, can you think of a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that using GCC (on linux), this code compiles just fine.
So I'd say that VisualStudio seems to be the source of the error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Windows or Visual Studio to verify, nor do I have much experience with lambda functions in C++, but perhaps you need to include the (albeit empty) parameter list in the function? i.e. change line 21 to

```
return build([](){});
```

Both versions compile with GCC, but perhaps Visual Studio is a bit more picky.

The other question I might have is whether the lambda function you're defining at line 24 will work out since its return value involves the lambda function you're defining inside the function itself.

Comment: Oh I standardized it now, thanks for pointing that out because it could confuse things. VS2012 accepts the no-inputs syntax just fine though.

Comment: @Timothy: The parameter list is optional, the smallest valid lambda expression is `[]{}`. This is not the problem.

Comment: @Xeo I know, originally I was omitting the parameter list as is valid. But it was attracting attention as the possible source of the error so I figured I'd use the syntax people are more familiar with so as not to distract.

Comment: @Anthony When you say "Both version compile with GCC" do you mean that you've taken the code I provided and successfully built it? If so, that's important news for me, because that probably means this is a VS2012 compiler error. I don't know how to run GCC to check myself - if you know it works using GCC that would be a huge help for me! -- I'm actually downloading GCC now so I can try to figure out how to do this sort of test on my own for the future.

Comment: @TimothyShields: Yes, sorry I wasn't more clear. With or without the empty argument list it compiled fine on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that behavior comply with the standard but with VC++ 2019 that error happen only with the option /permissive-, then when the strict mode is on.

Nevertheless here is how to solve the problem, by just casting the lambda with a reference type:

```
template <typename FUNC>
void f(FUNC& o){}

int main()
{
    f((std::function<void()>&)[](){});
    // or also:
    auto func = [](){};
    f(func);
}
```