# Lambda returning lambda incorrectly infers return type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, c++11, lambda

*This question is a continuation of a recent question of mine:

[What is this compiler error when using a lambda as a template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661981/what-is-this-compiler-error-when-using-a-lambda-as-a-template-parameter)*

Nov. 11, 2014: Microsoft has responded saying the fix for this bug should show up in the next major release of Visual C++.

---

This code fails to compile using the VS2012 (Update 2):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto f = []()
    {
        int n = 0;
        auto r = [=]{ return n; };
        return r;
    };
    return 0;
}
```

---

This is the compiler error I get:

```
1>  main.cpp
1>C:\test\main.cpp(7): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'main::<lambda_c5d1d707b91a1ddedc06eb080503550c>::()::<lambda_ac357c309731f4971c3269160ed9c24b>' to 'int (__cdecl *)(void)'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

---

- Is there a problem with the code according to C++11 specification?
- Is there a problem with the code according to VS2012's defined partial C++11 support?
- Or is this a VS2012 C++ compiler bug?

---

- Could someone point me to the place in the C++11 specification that talks about how lambdas must be implicitly castable to function pointers?

  - I recall this only being for *stateless* lambdas - those with empty capture clauses - which the inner lambda `r` is *not*
  - So why does it appear that the inferred return type of lambda `f` is a function pointer, namely `int (__cdecl *)(void)`?

Comment: Let's say it's because of a poor implementation :-)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Okay - but the cast to function pointer is explicitly *disallowed* for *stateful* lambdas, correct?

Comment: [Unsure how _"not"_ got into my earlier comment - sorry ;)] According to 5.1.2/6 the conversion _is_ required if it has no capture. The standard does not _explicitly_ prohibit the conversion from being included for stateful lambdas though. My understanding is since it's _unspecified_ the implementation is free to include the conversion even for stateful lambdas.

Comment: Interesting...  But it probably should only perform that conversion if it *has to*.  Does the standard address that aspect?  (Is there someplace where I can read the standard myself? I can't find it on the internet.)

Comment: For info, here is the link to the bug report on the Visual Studio web site: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808696/build-failed-when-one-lambda-without-the-specified-return-value-returns-another-lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although GCC 4.7.2 compiles this code it's ill formed. The lambda expression which initializes `f` is too complex for deducing the return type. Indeed, 5.1.2/4 says

> > If a lambda-expression does not include a trailing-return-type, it is as if the trailing-return-type denotes the following type:
> >
> > — if the compound-statement is of the form
> >
> > ```
> >    { attribute-specifier-seq[opt] return expression ; }
> > ```
> >
> > the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
> >
> > — otherwise, void.

Therefore, in this example the return type is `void` but the lambda is returning something else. The code should not compile.

I agree that the message given by Visual Studio is misleading.

**Update**: On this question

> > So would it be correct to say "In C++11, you cannot define a lambda that returns a stateful lambda"?

No. As per the C++11 quote below, the type returned by a lambda is `void` unless the body of the lambda contains just a single line with a `return expression;`. Hence, if you manage to create your stateful lambda in a return expression, then this is fine. For instance, the code below compiles in GCC 4.7.2, Clang 3.2 and Intel compiler 13.1.0: (It doesn't compile in VS2012 due to the aforementioned bug.)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int n = 5;
  auto f = [=] {
      return [=]{ return n; }; // creates a stateful lambda and returns it in a single line
  };
  std::cout << f()() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Therefore, in this example the return type is `void` . . ." - that is not consistent with what the compiler is saying. The compiler is saying the return type is `int (__cdecl *)(void)`. Furthermore, it is saying that it is incapable of performing the conversion from the lambda type on the line `auto r = ...;` to the return type of `f`, which is `int (__cdecl *)(void)`. Correct me if I'm wrong, because I'm kind of confused. :)

Comment: @TimothyShields: GCC is wrong to accept the code as C++11 (for C++14 CD it's correct though). Visual Studio is right in not accepting the code but for the wrong reason: it shouldn't try to convert a stateful lambda to a function pointer.

Comment: Could you give your thoughts on this recent related question of mine? I think the answers I got there may have been incorrect based on your insights. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661981/what-is-this-compiler-error-when-using-a-lambda-as-a-template-parameter

Comment: @TimothyShields: Regarding the other question, I'm sorry that I cannot add to what was said. I also tried your code with GCC 4.7.2 and it compiles fine. It seems that this is indeed a VS bug. I don't have VS2012 now but I tried with VS2010 and I got a similar error. The only difference between VS2012 and VS2010 is that the former says `T=void (__cdecl *)(void)` whereas the latter says `T=int`.

Comment: So would it be correct to say "In C++11, you cannot define a lambda that returns a stateful lambda"?